# Parse json com struct, erro ao passar para o array - Swift 4.0

Tags: json, swift, xcode

Estou com um erro com swift 4.0 no parse Json, estou usando struct Decodable para receber o json, sou novo no swift eu trabalho com objective-c.

```
struct dataInativa: Decodable {
    let dia_data:String
}

fileprivate func loadingDataInvalidas() {
    let urlString = "http..."
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                print("Erro na url:", err)
                   return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let datasInativas = try decoder.decode(dataInativa.self, from: data)

                print("Valores: ", datasInativas.dia_data)

            } catch let jsonErro {
                print("Erro no Json:", jsonErro)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Eu preciso passar para o array uma lista de datas como no exemplo abaixo:

```
self.somedays = ["2019/05/01","2019/05/02","2019/05/03","2019/05/04"]
```

O erro apresentado:

typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Alguém poderia dar uma help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisaria ver o JSON mas pela maneira que você quer o resultado deve ser um `Array`.

Na linha onde está escrito:

```
let datasInativas = try decoder.decode(dataInativa.self, from: data)
```

Substitua por:

```
let datasInativas = try decoder.decode(Array<dataInativa>.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, erra isso mesmo. abs